# How to get a ring with unit from a unit without unit

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Let Rng be the category of rings without unit, F the Funtor from Ring to Rng that forgets unit, Show that any object in Rng possesses a universal from F

I think it is similar to what we do in construct free abelian group, so I want to add some element into a ring without unit, let it acts as an unit, is it true? How to do it in detail

Thanks to anyone’s help

Comment: For a rng $R$, you can formally add an element $e$ and consider the set $A=\{r+ne:r\in R,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ where $(r_1+n_1e)(r_2+n_2e)=r_1r_2+n_1r_2+n_2r_1+n_1n_2e$.

Comment: @KentaS yeah that’s what I want to do, I get this ideal from $2\mathbb{Z}$ to get $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Note that the construction @KentaS sketches will _not_ give you $\mathbb Z$ when you put in $2\mathbb Z$ -- it gives a more complex ring that distinguishes between $2+0e$ and $0+2e$. That is a good thing, however, because if it did produe $\mathbb Z$ it could not be a left adjoint to the forgetful functor. To see that, note for example that there are 4 different _rng_ homomorphisms $2\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$, but there is only one _ring_ homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Troposphere very thanks for your warning!